# When SimpleMembershipProvider is not the default provider

Tags: membership-provider, simplemembership, custom-membershipprovider

When you have multiple membership providers configured, like:

```
    <membership defaultProvider="UmbracoMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="UmbracoMembershipProvider" type="umbraco.providers.members.UmbracoMembershipProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" defaultMemberTypeAlias="Another Type" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
    <add name="UsersMembershipProvider" type="umbraco.providers.UsersMembershipProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
    <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Then let's say, for a particular section in the site I want to use SimpleMembershipProvider for auth (the rest of the site will use the default provider i.e. UmbracoMembershipProvider) ... Therefore I need to initialize SimpleMembership with:

```
            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(
            Constants.Membership.ConnectionStringName,
            Constants.Membership.TableName, 
            Constants.Membership.UserIdColumnName, 
            Constants.Membership.UserNameColumnName, 
            false);
```

But it seems the above code only works when SimpleMembershipProvider is the defaultProvider. **I can't see a way to specify the provider name I want to use? Is this even possible? Or does simplymembership assume you have one membership and role provider defined?**

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleMembershipProvider` is an implementation of `ExtendedMembershipProvider`. Although `WebSecurity` will work with any implementation of the extended provider it has some questionable coupling to `SimpleMembershipProvider` if used.

Basically `SimpleMembershipProvider` requires initialisation via `WebSecurity`, otherwise it will throw an exception when the extended membership interface is used. If not initialised then it wraps the default `ASPNET` provider and can be used with the original `MembershipProvider` Interface and old schema.

The initialisation routine only initialises the default providers, provided they can be cast to the simple provider implementations. So yes you cannot use `SimpleMembershipProvider` or `SimpleRoleProvider` unless they are configured as the default instances.

There's some more information about the limitations of `SimpleMembershipProvider` [here](http://www.thecodeking.co.uk/2013/10/bettermembershipnet-10.html).

There is a work-around. You can use reflection to temporarily swap the provider to the default during initialisation and then switch it back. See [BetterMembership.Net](http://thecodeking.github.io/BetterMembership.Net) for an example of doing exactly that. This library extends `SimpleMembershipProvider` specifically for use in multi-provider systems.

```
membershipProviderField = typeof(Membership)
         .GetField("s_Provider", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

var originalMembershipProvider = membershipProviderField.GetValue(null);
membershipProviderField.SetValue(null, mySimpleMembershipProvider);

WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(...)

membershipProviderField.SetValue(null, originalMembershipProvider);
```